# Error compilation SFML debian

Tags: compilation, debian, sfml

I have install the SFML1.6 on debian for a school project.

On compilation i have theses error :

g++ -c main.cpp

g++ main.o -o bomberman -lsfml-graphics

> /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `sf::Unicode::Text::Text()'
>   /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to`sf::Context::GetGlobal()'
>   /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `sf::Window::OnEvent(sf::Event const&)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to`sf::Window::Create(sf::VideoMode, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, unsigned long, sf::WindowSettings const&)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `sf::Context::SetActive(bool)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to`typeinfo for sf::Window'
>   /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `sf::Window::Create(unsigned long, sf::WindowSettings const&)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to`sf::Window::GetHeight() const'
>   /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `sf::Window::Window()'
>   /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to`sf::Unicode::Text::Text(unsigned int const*)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `sf::Window::~Window()'
>   /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to`sf::Context::IsContextActive()'
>   /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `sf::Window::SetActive(bool) const'
>   /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to`sf::Unicode::Text::operator std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&() const'
>   /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `sf::Window::GetWidth() const'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [all] Error 1

I do not understand why theses error comes out.
libsfml-* is located in /usr/lib/ and all needed include in /usr/include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to link to the window and system library of sfml as well.

```
g++ main.o -o bomberman  -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

You should also read [this tutorial](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/start-linux.php)

Comment: And consider using the last version, that is 2.0, instead of that old, buggy and deprecated version 1.6.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the probleme came from my installation of the Sfml. My bad.